# Angular best practice for writing links (path, href) with html5 mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I am looking for best practices to write links and paths in Angular 1.5.

Given the following configuration:

```
angular.module('my-app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true});
    });
```

This does not work when I have a base ref in the html document:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="/my-app/"/>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <a ng-href="/my-section">My section</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Clicking the link put me at the absolute url /my-section, which does not exists. The same goes for the location service:

```
$location.path('/my-section') // Change my url at /my-section, not /my-app/my-section
```

It is easily fixed by replacing all my links with relative ones which has the effect or redirecting me to /my-app/my-section accordingly:

```
<a ng-href="my-section">My section</a>
$location.path('my-section')
```

However, according to the documentation of $location service:

> Path should always begin with forward slash (/), this method will add
>   the forward slash if it is missing. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location

This is basically telling me that the recommendations are to start all links with forward slash. How this is possible in my case ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should give only '/' as base href, if your app index looks like 'http://example.com/'.

If your index url looks like 'http://example.com/my-app/' then base href value would be '/my-section'.

Actually, it depends on url of the index page. So, please go by this way :)

Comment: So you are suggesting to use one base href per sections ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
    <head>
          <base href="/"></base>
        ...
    </head>
    <body>
        <a ng-href="my-app/my-section">My section</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Set base URL as forward slash

Comment: Modified my answer. please note